# How do I create a class that merges and returns a dataframe, but inherits from another class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, glob

I have two classes, I need the first class to take an input path which contains multiple files; and based off the file type, it inherits specific qualities such as a file provider name, group, and skiprow and footer values derived from provider name. Then I need to pass those values into the merging class so it can merge into one giant concatenated DataFrame, which then can be exported to csv.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import logging
import glob
from pandas import Series, DataFrame


class Provider(object):

    def __init__(self, path, group, type1_or_type2):
        self.group = group.lower()
        self.path = path
        self.type1_or_type2 = type1_or_type2
        self.skipfooter = 1
        if self.group == 'AXEL'.lower():
            self.skiprows = 3
        else:
            self.skiprows = 0

class Datamerge(Provider):

    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.dataframe = DataFrame


    @classmethod
    def massread(cls):
        """
        Select your path and index provider to merge the data into one large dataframe
        """
        allfiles = glob.glob(self.path +"/*.*")
        list_ = []
        for file_ in allfiles:
            df = pd.read_csv(file_, skiprows = self.skiprows, skipfooter = self.skipfooter, engine = 'python')
            list_.append(df)
            frame = pd.concat(list_)
        return cls(frame)

s = Provider('F:\Desktop/FNMRA','AXEL','type1')
s.frame.to_csv('F:\Desktop/test.csv')
```

The error that comes up is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Desktop\Python Scripts\massload.py", line 47, in <module>
    s.DataMerge
AttributeError: 'Provider' object has no attribute 'DataMerge'
[Finished in 3.1s with exit code 1]`

Comment: from the error traceback, can you please tell which line is generating this AttributeError. Also, I don't see where the function `datamerge` is defined.

Comment: Unfortunately you describe the problem in terms of the difficulty you are having rather than what you intend to achieve. Have you tried running this code? I can see several reasons why it might disappoint you

Comment: I tried running it but it does not work.  I need to input a path that acquires multiple files, and based off the file type it inherits specific qualities such as provider, group, and skiprow and footer values.  Then passes those values into the merging class so it can merge into one giant concatenated DataFrame, which then can be exported to csv.